# Adding edges to a TreeForm of an expression

Tags: graphs-and-networks, trees, igraphm

Say I have an expression `{1,{{2,3},4}}`. It's TreeForm looks as follows:

`{1,{{2,3},4}} //TreeForm`

[image]

Now, on each level of that tree I would like to draw an edge where there isn't one, i.e. between `1` and `List` (first level), between `List` and `4` (second level) and between `2` and `3` (third level). Is it possible to do it in an efficient way? Can I somehow control the direction of all of these edges (including already existing ones)? I tried to use `IGExpressionTree` from the IGraph package together with `EdgeAdd` but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: maybe ``EdgeAdd[GraphComputation`ExpressionGraph[{1, {{2, 3}, 4}} ], {2->3,4->7,5->6}]``?

Comment: @kglr Thanks! Does that work, I've tried `EdgeAdd[IGExpressionTree[{1, {{2, 3}, 4}}, VertexLabels->"Subexpression"],4\[UndirectedEdge]6]`, but that didn't work, I wonder why..

Comment: What if you have more than two nodes at the same level in the tree?

Comment: @amator2357 `IGExpressionTree` does not use the same vertex names as ``GraphComputation`ExpressionGraph``

Comment: @Szabolcs it'll never happen for my case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
g0 = GraphComputation`ExpressionGraph[{1, {{2, 3}, 4}} , ImageSize -> 200];
newedges = UndirectedEdge @@@ GatherBy[Rest@VertexList@g0, GraphDistance[g0, 1, #] &]
```

> `{2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 4 \[UndirectedEdge] 7, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 6}`

```
g1 = EdgeAdd[g0, newedges];
Row[{g0, g1}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `newedges` to  post-process the `TreeForm` of the input expression to add the new lines:

```
tf1 = TreeForm[{1, {{2, 3}, 4}}, DirectedEdges -> True, ImageSize -> Medium]; 
tf2 = RawBoxes[ToBoxes[tf1] /.  l : (_ArrowBox | _LineBox) :>
    {l, Dashing @ Small, LineBox @ # }] &[List @@@ newedges];
Row @ {tf1, tf2}
```

[image]

***If there are more than two nodes at the same level in the tree:***

```
g0 = GraphComputation`ExpressionGraph[{1, {{2, 3}, 4, 5}} , ImageSize -> 200];
newedges = Join @@ Map[UndirectedEdge @@@ # &, 
   Subsets[#, {2}] & /@ GatherBy[Rest@VertexList@g0, GraphDistance[g0, 1, #] &]]
```

> `{2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 4 \[UndirectedEdge] 7, 
>        4 \[UndirectedEdge] 8,  7 \[UndirectedEdge] 8, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 6}`

```
 g1 = SetProperty[EdgeAdd[g0, newedges],
    {EdgeShapeFunction -> {Alternatives @@ newedges :> "CurvedArc"}}]
 Row[{g0, g1}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[With IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM),

```
g = IGExpressionTree[{1, {{2, 3}, 4}}]
```

[image]

Notice that the vertices created by this function are lists (encoding subexpression positions), and their length is the same if they are on the same tree level.

```
IGExpressionTree[{1, {{2, 3}, 4}}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

Thus we can easily create the additional edges:

```
pathEdges[list_] := DirectedEdge @@@ Partition[list, 2, 1]

newEdges = Flatten[pathEdges /@ GatherBy[VertexList[g], Length]]
(* {{1} \[DirectedEdge] {2}, {2, 1, 1} \[DirectedEdge] {2, 1, 2}, {2, 1} \[DirectedEdge] {2, 2}} *)

EdgeAdd[g, newEdges]
```

[image]

If you never have more than two nodes at a level, then simply use

```
EdgeAdd[
 g,
 DirectedEdge @@@ GatherBy[Most@VertexList[g], Length]
]
```

Both of these rely on the order in which vertices are returned by `IGExpressionTree` (which is sorted) as well as on `GatherBy` not changing this order.